# Shuffle text while printing in python

Tags: python, shuffle, flush

I have write a simple python program

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def main():
   for i in range(11):
      sys.stdout.write("The value is %d"%int(i))
      sleep(1)
      sys.stdout.flush()
      
if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

It give me the following output with delay of 1s between each loop

```
The value is 0The value is 1The value is 2The value is 3The value is 4The value is 5The value is 6The value is 7The value is 8The value is 9The value is 10
```

but i need an output like this

```
This is 1
```

After 1s 1 should replaced by 2 in same place
If you did not understand my situation see my wordlist generator at https://github.com/azan121468/wordlist_gen
I want to apply same thing in my simple program but i am unable to do it
Please ***help*** me

Comment: Are you on Unix?

Comment: I don’t understand. Why do you write code that prints "The value is..." when you want it to print "This is 1"?

Comment: What does this have to do with shuffling anything?!

Comment: Is `curses` what you are looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#curses-programming-with-python ?

Comment: Terminology: "shuffle" refers to randomizing the order of a sequence.  I think you're using the term to refer to moving the cursor back and forth on the line.  The word "shuttle" might apply.

Comment: DirtyBit i am on windows

Comment: mkrieger1 sorry this is my mistake

Comment: Maurice Meyer no i am not looking for curses

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use the backspace (`'\b'`) character:

```
from time import sleep


def main():
    print('The value is 0', end='')
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print('\b' + str(i), end='')
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```